# Is it possible to view the source code of a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to get all of the courses for a college though:

http://ohiostate.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBDropDownView?jspStoreDir=ohiostate&deptId=&campusId=30747395&catalogId=10001&dojo.transport=xmlhttp&termId=44357427

And I was wondering if there was a way I could do this, like can I search the source code, or the database that it's accessing to display the classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

If you could, it would be a *major* security hole.
Imagine a similar servlet that stores credit card numbers for a shopping site (eg, Amazon).

Instead, you can contact the college and ask them for an API.

Comment: Gah, that's what I figured. So there's no way to download and pick at it like with Applets?

Comment: You cannot even be sure that it is really a servlet at the other end (could be PHP or anything).

Comment: @Thilo: Given the path, it's almost definitely a servlet.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot be sure ;-)