# Where can I get the source code of the servlet-api.jar?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a project that uses `servlet-api.jar`. When debugging, I wanted to step
into its classes (such as HttpServlet), but I got "Source not found attach source ".

Is there a way to get the source like all the Java sources? It would be good to have so I would be able to debug it and to step into the code.

Comment: [possible duplicate Is it possible to view the source code of a servlet?][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910766/is-it-possible-to-view-the-source-code-of-a-servlet?rq=1

Comment: @shareef: you're not understanding the concrete question.

Comment: From [Glassfish Trunk](http://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show/trunk/api/javaee-api/javax.servlet/src/main/java/javax/servlet?rev=55328)

Answer (score 7):

You can get apache source code from the apache tomcat website: http://tomcat.apache.org/index.html

Comment: What does apache has to do with servlet-api.jar?

Comment: I believe Apache created the `servlet-api.jar`.  It has since been repackaged and included in other redistributes, but the core came from Apache.  Here's Apache's documentation on it: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/

Comment: I thought that servlet-api.jar is part of the the servlet JSR 315: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315

Comment: I couldn't find the jar there.

Comment: The source code for the latest Tomcat (as of today) can be found at the bottom of this page.  The source code of the servlet-api.jar should be in there.  (of course your jar might not be the latest one :P )  http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

Comment: New link is: https://codeload.github.com/apache/tomcat/zip/8.5.49

Answer (score 6):

The Servlet API JAR is just interfaces (along with a few minor utility classes); there's nothing to step into.

Depending on your app-server, you can download source for implementation classes like `HttpRequest` (for Tomcat, instructions are [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/svn.html)). However, why do you feel there would be value stepping into those classes? They generally work well, and any problems are almost certainly in your own code.

Answer (score 3):

In addition if you are in eclipse or netbeans, and are using maven based project right click on the dependencies and download sources for your particular dependency.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the source from java2s.com

(version 3.0 of the servlet API): http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapi3020100224sourcesjar.htm

(or the older version 2)
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapi256114sourcesjar.htm

In fact java2s.com is a huge java source, program & jars resource.

Comment: Thanks @Mrinmoy. I made an edit to update your link to a newer version. I trust that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

**Intellij IDEA**

1. Download source codes from Apache, put somewhere at some stable place in your computer.
2. Try to go into some .jar function until "decompiled" result shows.
3. Click "Choose sources".
4. Select downloaded source codes and IDEA will do the rest :)

[image: Choose Sources in IDEA]

Answer (score 0):

To checkout the Javadoc on the classes or methods of "servlet-api.jar",
visit 
http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.27/src/

(for other versions of tomcat visit - 
http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/

and navigate to their "src" directory,

and download zip file for Windows(tar for Linux.) and finally

attach it within the IDE(Netbeans, Eclipse, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

- When you download the binary distribution of the apache tomcat, you can also download the corresponding source code distribution(on the same page).
- Simply download the source code distribution zip.
- move it to somewhere inside tomcat apache folder
- Point to source code distribution zip when Eclipse asks you for the source code attachment.